# ListView is messed up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have this method in my app:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) { 
    final MyObject alerta = (MyObject ) getItem(index);

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);

        dia = Integer.parseInt(alerta.getDias());
        status = alerta.isStatus();

        salvaStatus(status, index);
        salvaDia(""+dia, index);
    }               

    final TextView tvDias = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDiasConfiguracoesAlerta);
    final Button btStatus = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btStatusConfiguracoesAlerta);
    final Button btLeft = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btLeftDiasConfiguracoesAlertas);
    final Button btRight = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btRightDiasConfiguracoesAlertas);     
    final TextView tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeAlertaConfiguracoes);
    final TextView tvStatusAntecedencia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvStatusConfiguracoesAlerta);

    tvNome.setText(alerta.getNome());   
    mudaTexto(tvDias, tvStatusAntecedencia, dia);

    if(status){
        btStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botao_configuracao_on);
    } else {
        btStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botao_configuracao_off);
        btLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tvDias.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tvStatusAntecedencia.setText("Desligado...");
    }
 return view }
```

Inside the if I get the value from status.
Than, I handle the layout in if(status).

I have other metho that change this layout too, but when I scroll the list
it get the old value from status and messed up the layout.

**EDIT**

The first time the list appear, it appear a green button, when I click this button he becomes red. But when I scroll the list others buttons become red too.

Comment: What do you mean by "messed up the layout", please provide specifics to what the problem is.

Comment: The first time the list appear, it appear a green button, when I click this button he becomes red. But when I scroll the list others buttons become red too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take move of the code in the first 'if' to outside the 'if':

```
if (view == null) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);
 }
 dia = Integer.parseInt(alerta.getDias());
 status = alerta.isStatus();
 salvaStatus(status, index);
 salvaDia(""+dia, index);
```

When your view is being reused, you're not updating the status variable correctly, that's why your view get's messed up.